# Send params from a Rails view to Javascript to make an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I've got a Rails project that lists products.  I've got some JavaScript code that I use to do an infinite scroll on the products.  I'm now adding a filtering feature that allows the user to filter the products.  I have the params in the URL that tell the controller what to filter and that's working fine, but when I scroll to the bottom of the page, my JavaScript file makes an AJAX call to load more products, but I can't figure out how to get the params from the Rails view into the data field of that AJAX call.

What I've tried is this code in the view to assign the params to a variable in JavaScript:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var params = '<%= params.to_json.html_safe %>';
<% end %>
```

And then my AJAX call to load more products is this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/products/index.js',
    type:'GET',
    data:params
  })
```

The problem is the params that are used when the Products controller action is called aren't formatted correctly.  Here's what it ends up looking like:

```
Started GET "/products/index.js?{%22search_term%22:%22product%22,%22option_one%22:[%224%22],%22option_two%22:[%223%22],%22order%22:%22newest%22}"
```

It's replacing the quotes in the params hash with %22.  Another thing I can see that might be an issue is that option_one and option_two are arrays that can contain multiple numbers.  I'm not sure if that will be handled 
correctly either.

I haven't been able to find a question on here that has the same issue.  Thanks!

Comment: you can send the params directly without using `.to_json.html_safe` .
like this: `var params = '<%= params %>'`

Comment: What worked was sending it with the .to_jason.html_safe but without the quotes so that the JavaScript code handled it like a json hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was my formatting in the Rails view.  I shouldn't have had the single quotes.  Here's what worked:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var params = <%= params.to_json.html_safe %>;
<% end %>
```

It looks like JavaScript can handle the json object and use that for the data parameter in the AJAX call and by having the quotes there, it was turning it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the key values of parameters to be sent then directly send the params in **data** attribute.

```
var params = '<%= params %>';

$.ajax({
 url: '/products/index.js',
 type: 'GET',
 data: params
});
```

Comment: Here's what happens when I do that.  I get this when I console.log(params):

Comment: `Started GET "/job_profiles/active.js?{&quot;search_term&quot;=&gt;&quot;product&quot;,%20&quot;option_one&quot;=&gt;[&quot;4&quot;],%20&quot;option_two&quot;=&gt;[&quot;3&quot;],%20&quot;order&quot;=&gt;&quot;newest&quot;}"`

Comment: The problem was the single quotes.  Once I removed them, then it worked.